# ¿Por qué me sale error 404 al usar .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

Estoy tratando de ocultar las extensiones .HTML y .PHP de mi sitio web, he utilizado un archivo .htaccess, sin embargo al querer ir a un sitio me sale error 404, me podrían decir qué estoy haciendo mal por favor?

Cabe decir que ya estoy montando mi página a un servidor

Mi archivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Mi menú de navegación:

```
<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre-nosotros">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
                    <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Certificación de sistemas de gestión</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="iso9001-2015">ISO 9001:2015</a></li>
                            <li><a href="iso14001-2015">ISO 14001:2015</a></li>
                            <li><a href="iso45001-2018">ISO 45001:2018</a></li>
                            <li><a href="iso-IEC-27001">ISO/IEC 27001:2013</a></li>
                            <li><a href="iso37001-2016">ISO 37001:2016</a></li>
                            <li><a href="iso28000-2007">ISO 28000:2007</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="proceso-certificacion">Proceso de Certificación</a></li>
                    <li><a href="QFSpoliticas">QFS Políticas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactanos">Contáctanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://qfscerts.com/client.html">Clientes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

He quitado de los `a href` las extensiones porque así vi que se hacia

Y he puesto mi archivo .htaccess en la raíz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió muy bien =)